# Buscar y Eliminar registros duplicados MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Bien, mi situación es la siguiente, tengo una Base de datos algo grande, y existen una gran cantidad de **registros duplicados** (en realidad hay muchos que se repiten **mas de dos veces** pero no se como llamarle a eso). Lo que busco es una **consulta** que me ayude a **buscar**, o quizas **eliminar directamente** los **registros duplicados** y **dejandome solamente uno**. Hasta ahora tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) Total
FROM usuarios
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

La cual me selecciona los registros que estan repetidos mas de una vez, o en este caso, los registros que tienen el mismo email mas de una vez. Esta consulta me arroja nada mas y nada menos que **58.680** resultados, y pues, resulta bastante engorroso tener que borrarlos uno por uno. Tengo la sensación de que esta consulta se puede extender para lograr lo que quiero pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, espero puedan auxiliarme. Si sirve de algo mi gestor de Base de Datos es **Phpmyadmin 4.7.4**.

Comment: Tu consulta funciona bien validando la cantidad de registros que encuentre, pero solo para la columna **email**, que otros campos duplicados te interesa validar, serviría la estructura completa de la tabla

Comment: @WalterCordova Pues la tabla solo posee 3 columnas. La tabla se llama **usuarios** y sus columnas son **id**,**nombre**,**email**

Comment: Supongamos que tienes `[id=1, nombre=juan, email=pepe@gmail.com]` y `[id=2, nombre=pedro,  email=pepe@gmail.com]`, ¿Cual de los dos eliges para borrar?

Comment: La verdad no importa cual borre, lo único que requiero es que solo exista en email por registro. Nada de día o mas enzima iguales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamete este es tu problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para solucionarlo :

Primer paso  : Desactiva el safe updates mode ( esto si utilizas Workbench )
lo puedes hacer desde el menu Edit -> preferences

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segudo paso : Crea una tabla temporal con los correos únicos

```html
create temporary table t1
select * from usuarios group by email;
```

te quedara asi ( sin correos repetidos )
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tercer Paso : Borrar repetidos

```html
DELETE FROM usuarios
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM t1 );
```

listo con  eso borrarías los registros con correos repetido.

Comment: La verdad no he logrado comprender la consulta, ¿Podrías explicarme cual sería la salida exactamente?

Comment: Vale mira la primera consulta creara una tabla temporal. Con todos los id de los registros que tengan correos unicos.(por el grupo by correo)   la segunda consulta borrara los registros cuyos id no estén en la tabla temporal que acabamos de crear ( es decir los repetidos)

Comment: Si haces un selec count(*)  from t1.    Deberá darte la misma cantidad que sin hicieras un SELECT email, COUNT(*) Total FROM usuarios GROUP BY email.

Comment: No se si me doy a entender.

Comment: Revisa el código de tu respuesta, no hace lo que está solicitando el OP. Tal como esta ahora, no borraría nada.

Comment: Ciertamente, además falta cerrar paréntesis en la primera consulta.

Comment: ya esta corregida y documentada la respuesta

Answer (score 13):

Hay varias formas de hacer lo que quieres.

## I. Mediante `JOIN`:

Esta técnica consiste en **unir la tabla consigo misma** mediante `JOIN`. Y usar una comparación combinada de la columna `id` (que se supone no es repetida nunca) y la columna repetida (`email` en este caso).

La consulta sería esta:

```
DELETE t1 FROM usuarios t1
INNER JOIN usuarios t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.email = t2.email;
```

Veamos un ejemplo completo:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/PIK1389)**</kbd>

```
-- I. Datos de prueba 

CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO usuarios (first_name,last_name,email) 
VALUES ('Pedro ','Pérez','p.pedro@gmail.com'),
       ('Juan','Roa','r.juan@icloud.com'),
       ('Santiago','Guerrero','g.santiago@hotmail.com'),
       ('Juan','Roa','r.juan@icloud.com'),
       ('Andrés ','Brito','b.andres@live.com'),
       ('Juan','Roa','r.juan@icloud.com'),
       ('Santiago','Guerrero','g.santiago@hotmail.com'),
       ('Felipe','Castro','c.felipe@me.com')
       ;

/* Prueba de datos antes de borrar*/

SELECT 
    id, email
FROM usuarios
ORDER BY email;    

-- II. Borrar mediante JOIN

DELETE t1 FROM usuarios t1
INNER JOIN usuarios t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.email = t2.email; 


/* Prueba de datos después de borrar*/

SELECT 
    id, email
FROM usuarios
ORDER BY id;    

-- III. Restringir duplicados

ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD UNIQUE (email);

/* 
    Prueba de la nueva restricción creada:
    al descomentar el código tendremos el siguiente error:
    Error(s), warning(s): Duplicate entry 'p.pedro@gmail.com' for key 'email'
*/

-- INSERT INTO usuarios (first_name,last_name,email) VALUES ('Pedro ','Pérez','p.pedro@gmail.com');
```

#### Resultados:

**Antes de borrar los duplicados:**

```
id  email
5   b.andres@live.com
8   c.felipe@me.com
3   g.santiago@hotmail.com
7   g.santiago@hotmail.com
1   p.pedro@gmail.com
2   r.juan@icloud.com
4   r.juan@icloud.com
6   r.juan@icloud.com
```

**Después de borrar los duplicados:**

```
id  email
1   p.pedro@gmail.com
2   r.juan@icloud.com
3   g.santiago@hotmail.com
5   b.andres@live.com
8   c.felipe@me.com
```

Nótese que aquí se conservaron los valores cuyo `id` era menor. Si se quieren conservar aquellos cuyo `id` sea mayor, sólo hay que poner el `WHERE` de la consulta así: `... WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND t1.email = t2.email`

Nótese que aplicando esta técnica, habrá saltos en la columna `id`. Si se quiere una tabla con mejor orden en dicha columna, ver el método mencionado a continuación.

---

## II. Mediante la creación de una nueva tabla

Esta técnica consiste en crear una nueva tabla con la misma estructura de la tabla original. Insertar los registros desde la tabla con duplicados aplicando un filtro que evite los duplicados (`GROUP BY` en este caso)  y luego borrar la tabla vieja, renombrando la nueva.

**1. Creamos una copia vacía de la tabla `usuarios`**

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios_copy LIKE usuarios;
```

**2. Insertamos en la nueva tabla todos los registros, agrupando por la columna repetida**

Hay dos formas de hacer esto:

- Si quieres tener una nueva tabla con la columna `id` ordenada, puedes nombrar explícitamente cada columna, indicando el valor `NULL` para la columna auto incremental. Esto permitirá que dicha columna obtenga su valor de forma natural:

  ```
     INSERT INTO usuarios_copy   
          SELECT 
              NULL,
              first_name,
              last_name,
              email 
           FROM usuarios 
           GROUP BY email;
  ```
- Si no te importa tener tantos saltos en la columna `id`, puedes hacer la inserción así:

  ```
     INSERT INTO usuarios_copy   
          SELECT *
           FROM usuarios 
           GROUP BY email;
  ```

**3. Borramos la tabla vieja y renombramos la nueva**

```
DROP TABLE usuarios;
ALTER TABLE usuarios_copy RENAME TO usuarios;
```

En la prueba de datos, obtendrás este resultado. Nótese que aquí la columna `id` recobró su orden normal:

```
id  email
1   b.andres@live.com
2   c.felipe@me.com
3   g.santiago@hotmail.com
4   p.pedro@gmail.com
5   r.juan@icloud.com
```

Veamos un ejemplo completo aplicando esta posibilidad:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/FFSQ15454)**</kbd>

---

## III. Resolver el problema de raíz

De poco servirá hacer todo el trabajo anterior, si no cambiamos el diseño de la tabla, haciendo que la columna `email` sea `UNIQUE`, o sea, que no permita emails duplicados.

Esto se lograría con una sola línea de código, la cual hay que ejecutar una vez nuestra tabla esté **limpia** de duplicados:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD UNIQUE (email);
```

Si ahora nosotros intentamos insertar algún duplicado:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (first_name,last_name,email) 
VALUES ('Pedro ','Pérez','p.pedro@gmail.com');
```

El DBMS nos lo impedirá, diciendo lo siguiente:

> ```
> Duplicate entry 'p.pedro@gmail.com' for key 'email'
> ```

**NOTA:** Puede que en una tabla como esta, haya un grupo de columnas que sean `UNIQUE`, en ese caso, habría que crear un índice único combinado... Pero ese es otro asunto. Solamente quería indicar que este tipo de problemas hay que resolverlos de raíz.

Comment: Excelente, me hafuncionado el método 2. Entonces, una ultima duda, al aplicar el método 3, no importa si ya tengo una columna como clave primaria? Puedo aplicarle ese método a la columna email sin ningun problema?

Comment: He intentado realizar la consulta en cuestion y me lanza el siguiente error #1170 - Columna BLOB column 'email' usada en especificación de clave sin tamaño de la clave

Comment: @Jalkhov una cosa es la clave primaria y otra cosa es la restricción `UNIQUE`. Tú puedes tener una clave primaria y aparte una o varias columnas como `UNIQUE`. Lo que hace `UNIQUE` es evitar que se repitan datos de las columnas especificadas. En cuanto al error que te da, ¿qué tipo de dato es la columna `email` en la tabla? **Espero** que no la tengas declarada del tipo `BLOB` o del tipo `TEXT`.

Comment: Mmm, bueno ciertamente es tipo text, la verdad aún me falta manejar los tipos de datos en sql, seguido tengo errores con eso. ¿Podrías decirme el por que no se puede y que tipo de datos debería ser?

Comment: @Jalkhov como su nombre lo indica, el tipo `TEXT` es para almacenar **texto**, es decir, párrafos completos, miles y miles de caracteres. Por ejemplo si tienes que guardar un artículo completo, entonces sí convendría usar un campo del tipo `TEXT` pero para el email, con un campo del tipo `VARCHAR(100)` o `VARCHAR(150)` siendo generosos, bastaría, porque un email no creo que pase de 100 caracteres. Si tú usas `TEXT` para guardar un email estás desperdiciando espacio, y si tienes que poner un índice en ese campo tendrás el problema que se te está presentando ahora.

Comment: Correcto, ya cambié todo lo correspondiente, ejecuté la consulta y me devuelve lo siguiente:  **MySQL ha devuelto un conjunto de valores vacío (es decir: cero columnas). (La consulta tardó 56,0000 segundos.)
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD UNIQUE (email)**. ¿Se ha realizado correctamente?

Comment: @Jalkhov todo parece indicar que si. Puedes probar a insertar un email repetido. Sí ha funcionado te impedirá agregar ese dato. O bien puedes ejecutar un `DESCRIBE tabla` y te mostrará datos sobre la tabla, incluyendo los índices.

Comment: Si, todo correcto, me genera el error que me indicaste en el **método 3**. Muchas gracias. Tendré en cuenta todo lo muestras aquí para evitar futuros dolores de cabeza. Ya se puede dar por resuelto mi problema.

Comment: Exelente!!! como se nota que este tipo sabe de lo que habla. excelente. muy bien explicado