# eliminar valores repetidos de un grupo con SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero eliminar valores duplicados de una tabla sql pero no he podido eliminar solo tengo esta query que cuenta los valores repetidos de cada grupo, como puedo agregarle un delete a esta query?, Esta query ya esta filtrada solo no se como colocarle el DELETE

```html
select TRANSIT_F, count(*)
from TBL  where ID_CARGA in (3940630,
3940631,
3940632,
3940633,
3940634,
3940635,
3940636,
3940637,
3940638,
3940639,
3940640,
3940641,
3940642)
group by TRANSIT_F
having count(TRANSIT_F) > 1
```

Lo que quiero eliminar son los repetidos de cada registro, en una columna tengo el valor unico y en la otra el numero de veces que se encuentra repetido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual es el valor que queres dejar y cuales los que queres borrar? muchas veces es mas facil crear una tabla nueva con los valores sin repetir...

Comment: Posible duplicado de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148640/buscar-y-eliminar-registros-duplicados-mysql

Comment: @gbianchi lo que quiero eliminar es lo que me regresa la consulta, que son los que estan duplicados

Comment: @Ivxn podrias explicar porque la pregunta que te marcamos como duplicada no contesta tu duda?

Comment: @gbianchi 1. No estoy usando MySQL 2. No estoy usando workbench, 3. No es lo que necesito hacer

Comment: Probaste alguno de los 3 metodos que no son particulares de mysql, en la respuesta que tiene 6 votos? esos no necesariamente son para mysql, si no que sirven para cualquier base. Si no estas de acuerdo con nuestro punto de vista, podemos llevar el tema a [meta]